# Fake anonymous user to edit own post?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I rejected this [Suggested Edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8444042), but then I saw it being accepted by the original questioner, but judging by the time stamp and his "Please help me out" pleading in the comments is there some sort of bug that can be exploited to allow you to accept your own posts via anonymous editing?

Comment: Looks like you assume something smelly is going on.  There's some evidence for that, nothing conclusive, we're not allowed to talk about it.

Comment: @Hans, wouldn't making a dedicated site help resolving things we cannot talk about? The number of possible *consumers* isn't that small...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is almost *always* indicative of someone being unknowingly disenfranchised from their account. It happens when teams share computers, and all of the logging in / out of all the things. We see a reasonable amount of support requests from folks about this, sometimes not realizing that they were logged in as a teammate and posting something as them.

It looks weird, but there's almost *never* malice at play.

Comment: That makes most sense to me, that he got confused with the workflow and ended up accepting his own comment without realising what was going on.

Comment: Because we permit anon edits and such, the UX changes between logged in and not logged in (or logged in as someone else entirely) are _very_ subtle. Maybe even too subtle, but fixing that without making it worse in other ways would be really difficult.

Comment: Would a "posting as John Doe" with the profile image right next to the submit button help?

Answer (score 9):

You can ***always*** accept or reject suggested edits on your own posts.

I honestly can't tell what's supposed to be "bugged" here. The OP accepted the edit, then you modified it a bit.

There's over 30 minutes between his [*"Please help me out"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781471/how-to-convert-id-as-order-number-in-ng-options-group-by#comment49719473_30781716) plea, and [the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8444042). I don't see how they're related.

Comment: I couldn't really see some random anonymous editor adding "Please help me out" to a post around the same time as the OP was adding comments. I'm also not sure how an anonymous person can edit posts.

Comment: People make stupid suggestions some times. Or maybe the OP got logged out before he edited the post. Anonymous users can't edits posts. They _can_ suggest edits, though.

Comment: @KenY-N: Anyone can suggest an edit. Anonymous edits aren't unheard of, but they're a lot less common in the queues. Probably that's because there's no +2 rep for an accepted edit, which really seems like the only possible exploit here; logging out to make an edit and then logging in to accept it is just more hoops to jump through if one could just, y'know, make the edit already.

Comment: But, "Please help me out" would be rejected through the normal review procedure for a self-edit, so logout->edit->login->accept are hoops worth jumping through.

Comment: No, not worth it, since you could just as well edit that in yourself. There's no point in suggesting an (anonymous) edit on your own posts.